# Using Partial Cnfiguration without hardcoding configuration name in LCM property

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I would like to combine few small DSC configurations into one MOF file. I know there is something like Partial Configuration in Powershell v5, however to use this feature i have to reconfigure LCM on target node everytime when amount of configurations is changed (which is impossible because i want to configure LCM **manually** only once on first DSC configuration).

Unfortunatelly DSC do not allow to reconfigure LCM via DSC Resource which means i cannot change this setting by "Pull Mode" on local machine.

I'm still wondering why LCM do not support "`*`" inside PartialConfigurtion property when it could be very usefull specially when every configuration uses GUID anyway (*.GUID.MOF)

Have you ever found any solution to workaround this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

DSC doesn't require all partial configuration fragments to be available at the time of applying the configuration. So you can still populate many partialConfig ahead of time in LCM which may become available at some point of time. This gives you some flexibility for not modifying LCM settings every time you need to add another partial configuration. I would also suggest opening a uservoice issue request @ https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/category/148047-desired-state-configuration-dsc for:

1. Allowing '*' in partial configuration.
2. Allowing updating meta-config from pull server.